# FileReader not triggering load event

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

I have this function which I am trying to unit-test. It is called when a `file` is selected from `HTML` `<input>`. I am creating a `FileReader` which I suppose should fire `load` event. I want to call my function `_handleReaderLoaded` when `load` is fired.

```
handleFileSelect(files:ArrayLike<File>){
    console.log("got file upload event: ");
    console.log(" image attachment count: ",this.currentImageAttachmentCount);
    if(this.currentImageAttachmentCount >= this.maxImageAttachmentCount)
    {
      console.log("reached max attachment size");
      this.showDialog("You can't attach more files",new DialogContext("",""));
      return;
    }
    console.log("files selected:",files);
    console.log("total selected: ",files.length);
    for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
      console.log("files name:",files[i].name);
      console.log("files object:",files[i])
    }

    //working with only 1 file at the moment
    let file = files[0];
    console.log("file at index 0 ",file);
    if (files && file) {
      console.log("reading file");
      let reader:FileReader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload =this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
      reader.onerror = this.debugPrintFileEvents.bind(this); //what is the purpose of bind and what does this refer to?
      reader.onloadend = this.debugPrintFileEvents.bind(this);
      reader.onloadstart = this.debugPrintFileEvents.bind(this);
      reader.onprogress = this.debugPrintFileEvents.bind(this);
      reader.onabort = this.debugPrintFileEvents.bind(this);
      ;
      //The readAsBinaryString method is used to start reading the contents of the specified Blob or File.
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      this.currentImageAttachmentCount++;
    }
  }
```

but I notice that the `load` event is not getting fired. The unit test case is

```
fit('should upload maximum 3 image files', () => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    let file1 = new File(["foo1"],"foo1.txt");

spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'_handleReaderLoaded');
spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'showDialog');
newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);


  });
```

The following are the debug prints in the browser window. You'll notice that there is no `load` event, thus my function `_handleReaderLoaded` is not getting executed

```
got file upload event: 
context.js:1972  image attachment count:  0
context.js:1972 files selected: [File(4)]
context.js:1972 total selected:  1
context.js:1972 files name: foo1.txt
context.js:1972 files object: File(4) {name: "foo1.txt", lastModified: 1548101766552, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jan 21 2019 20:16:06 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 4, …}
context.js:1972 file at index 0  File(4) {name: "foo1.txt", lastModified: 1548101766552, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jan 21 2019 20:16:06 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 4, …}
context.js:1972 reading file
context.js:1972 got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 0, total: 4, type: "loadstart", …}
context.js:1972 got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 4, total: 4, type: "progress", …}
context.js:1972 got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 4, total: 4, type: "loadend", …}
```

Interestingly, if I change the `onload` handler to this

then I see that that handler is called

```
reader.onload = function(){
        console.log('onload event for reader ',reader);
      };

got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 0, total: 4, type: "loadstart", …}
context.js:1972 got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 4, total: 4, type: "progress", …}
context.js:1972 onload event for reader  _global.(anonymous function) {__zone_symbol__originalInstance: FileReader} <<----- THIS GETS CALLED
context.js:1972 got file reader event  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 4, total: 4, type: "loadend", …}
```

the `_handleReaderLoaded` method is

```
  _handleReaderLoaded(event:FileReaderProgressEvent) {
    console.log("got load event of file reader ",event);
    let thumbnailTemplateViewRef:EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

    /*
     When the read operation is finished, the result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file.
     */
    let binaryString = event.target.result;
    this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
    console.log(this.base64textString);

    /*show image as thumbnail*/
    let src = "data:image/png;base64,";
    src += this.base64textString;

    //create new ids for div, img and a in the template
    ++this.consecutiveIdGenerator;
    let divId = "thumbnail-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator);
    console.log("div id "+divId);

    let imgId = "img-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator);
    console.log("img id "+imgId);


    let closeId = "close-button-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator)

    console.log("close Id is "+closeId);

    //TODOM - define context as a class so that it can be used in new question and question details
    thumbnailTemplateViewRef = this.thumbnailContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.thumbnailTemplateRef,{option:{divId:divId,
        imgId:imgId,
        closeId:closeId,
        imgSrc:src}});

    //store the reference of the view in context of the template. This will be used later to retrive the index of the view when deleting the thumbnail
    thumbnailTemplateViewRef.context.option.viewRefId = thumbnailTemplateViewRef;

  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code for _handleReaderLoaded - all the other events are set up to explicitly log so it makes sense you'd see those at least. By the way, `bind` creates a new function which, when called, uses whatever value you passed to bind as the internal `this` param. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: I added print in `_handleReaderLoaded` as well - `_handleReaderLoaded(fileReaderEvt:FileReaderProgressEvent) {
    console.log("got file reader event ",fileReaderEvt); ...}`

Comment: I added an observation. If I don't use bind then onload handler gets called. I don't understand why though

Comment: It might have to do with how or where _handleReaderLoaded is defined. Is it part of the same class?

Comment: yes, all the methods are part of the same Typescript class.  I have added code for _handleReaderLoaded as well. The file being uploaded is an image file. It basically creates a Thumbnail of the image file.

Comment: Won't help you with the why it doesn't work, but please don't use this code. readAsBinaryString is only there for backward compatibility, and should not be used. For what you are doing, there is already a readAsDataURL method. But you don't even need this, since you seem to only want to display this preview image, then simply use `src =`[`URL.createObjectURL(file);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). This will save memory, and simplify a lot your code since there won't be any callback needed.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido. I have changed to readAsDataURL for now. I'll read up URL.createObjectURL.

Answer (score 0):

Urrrg!!!! I am spying on `_handleReaderLoaded`, so obviously its original implementation will not be called! I should have used `spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'_handleReaderLoaded').and.callThrough();`